# Google translation Oauth2.0 from browser

Tags: javascript, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am creating a simple web page, that make use of the Google Translation Service.

The page has a field, to receive the input from the user and a button to trigger the call to the Translation API. It returns the result translation to the user.

I've successfully done the flow above using Ajax requests, but the access token 
is hard-coded into my method and I want to change that to a call that gets sent whenever the token expires (currently I have to request a new token using the Google CLI and replace it in my code).

I have a very basic knowledge of Oauth2.0 and I've read the Google Documentation but couldn't find a part of it that would tell me the endpoint to call to get an access token from the client-side.

Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form id="translate_form">
    <input id="input" />
    <button id="translate_button">Translate</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$("#translate_form").submit(function () {
        var text = $("#input").val()
        sendTranslationRequest(text);
        return false;
    })


    function sendTranslationRequest(inputText) {
        var requestBody = {
            q: inputText,
            source: "en",
            target: "fr",
            format: 'text'
        }

        translationAjaxRequest(requestBody);
    }

    function translationAjaxRequest(requestBody) {
        var access_token = [access_token]
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
            success: function (response) {
                var translatedText = response.data.translations[0].translatedText
                alert(translatedText)
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("An error occurred on the request:", response)
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant endpoints to get an access token and refresh it are:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

However, you’ll need to perform several steps in order to get an access token and a refresh token. You may want to review this guide on [Using OAuth2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer). It will walk you through the [prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#prerequisites), [obtaining an access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#obtainingaccesstokens) and [refreshing](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) your token.

Alternatively, you may use an [API Key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys). Just be mindful of the recommendations on how to [secure it](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#securing_an_api_key), since a stolen API Key may be used to generate calls that would be charged directly to your billing account.